# Consultar concurrentemente en Go

Tags: go

Estoy realizando un proyecto universitario de booking de hoteles. Tengo 3 microservicios: uno de "ficha de hotel" (guarda la informacion de cada hotel), otro de "search" (busca filtrando por ciudad y por fecha inicio y fecha fin, y el ultimo es el microservicio "disponibilidad" que se encarga de calcular la misma. Estoy teniendo varias dudas: en el MS de disponibilidad tengo que hacer una funcion GetAvailability que ese sería el filtro que se llama desde search. Para hacer esa funcion necesito el dato "cantidad de habitaciones" que esta en el MS ficha de hotel, como hago para llamar a ese dato? Y otra pregunta relacionada, el MS Search primero filtra por ciudad y ese resultado le trae la funcion GetAvailability para finalmente filtrar por fechas, eso como se hace? Me está costando el tema de la comunicación entre microservicios.

Comment: podrias poner algunos ejemplos de código para que veamos que significa microservicio, por ejemplo, y poder ayudarte con más contexto? Gracias